# Using regular expression in python to extract a list of strings from a large string

Tags: python, regex

I have a large string called x.

In the string I have a certain patterns which I want to extract the string between the patterns.

In the string I have a pattern which consists of a squared bracket which has some numbers or letters (or both), followed by the word legend followed by date in the format of dd/mm/yyyy or d/m/yyyy. So the pattern I want to find is for e.g.,: `"[Something] legend dd/mm/yy".`

Now after I find this pattern I want to add to a list all the string after that pattern all the way up to the next time the pattern exists. Also in the final case after the final pattern, the last element of the string is just the remainder of string.

Example:

```
"this is test data [3232] legend 2/1/2014 Who was a wonderful gentleman. Note there was another [dsf] legend 03/02/2015 also was great and there is also a cat [fsfs] legend 02/0/2014 test test test"
```

Output:

```
list = ["Who was a wonderful gentleman. Note there was another", "also was great and there is also a cat", "test test test"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what's not working about it?

Comment: You have almost done it I guess, try with `re.split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a fairly simple regular expression:

```
results = re.split('\[\w+\] legend \d+/\d+/\d+', input_string)
```

**Explanation:**

`re.split(ptrn, string)` finds a pattern, and then splits the input string  on that pattern and returns a list. The pattern is "consumed" or removed in the process. As for the pattern:

- `\[` captures a literal [.
- `w+` captures one or more letters or numbers (or underscore).
- `legend` captures a the literal "legend" surrounded by spaces.
- `\d+/\d+/\d+` is a standard date capture.

Granted, you get some leading/trailing spaces, but you can fix that with a `.rstrip()`